# Best grammar-checking software

Tags: software, tools

What is the best grammar-checking software for checking grammar errors in novels and screenplays?

Comment: It's funny to see a question of the format so unwelcome on StackExchange because "choosing the best is subjective" or "this will create an endless list of answers, all valid" when the answer to the question is "none". We have fairly good spellcheckers but it's still a good several years before a half-decent grammar-checker is created. (that doesn't mean none exist, simply none good exist.)

Comment: @SF. - That answer is probably why this question is still open.

Comment: There isn't one, because there can't be. Spelling can be checked. Certain matters of agreement can be checked. Certain idioms and common phrasings can be checked. Certain items of punctuation can be checked. But grammar itself is too tied to meaning to ever be checked. Software would have to know what was intended to know if it had been said, but what has been said is the only clue it has to what was intended.

Comment: @MarkBaker Of course there can be grammer checking software, because grammar can be checked. You can do it (I presume), because you can infer from the text what was supposed to be meant, and potentially software can infer this intended meaning just as well as you can and check the grammar against it. That computers have to become quite intelligent to do so does not mean that, as you write, "there can't be".

Comment: This question would have been far better if it had specified a language. Given that OP apparently hasn't been on the network in three years (most recently seen on [ell.se] in January 2014), though, I doubt that we'll see the question revised.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while it has historical value, it would be better memorialized in the site than left open for new answers. The tools in question are evolving too fast for the Q&A to satisfy StackExchange guidelines. Any answer will be left in the dust in a matter of months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked a few tools like Grammarly, spellcheckplus, writing dynamo and white smoke. I felt white smoke is the worst of all.

Grammarly, spellcheckplus and writing dynamo are all very similar in value, but I found Grammarly is better than both spellcheckplus and writing dynamo. Still Grammarly doesn't catch all the issues, it catches at least some of them.

Also I've found you should know at least some level of grammar to use any of these tools.

Anyway Grammarly is better than others. Check it out.

Answer (score 14):

None of them. There is no commercial grammar checker that I know of which even approaches the ability of a halfway-competent native speaker. If you're thinking that grammar-checking software will help you with your typos and grammar mistakes, think again. This is one thing that still requires human intelligence.

Comment: How is that an answer to the question? We all know that grammar checking software products are not perfect. You should at least tell us what is the best software you know.

Comment: microsoft word is at least as well known for approving bad grammar and disproving good grammar as it is known for having a grammar checker. At one point I was reading requests for a word-processor for  Linux and all the recommendations were dismissed as not having a grammar checker, which was rebutted with "so that explains why you can't write." A bad grammar checker can be worse than no grammar checker.

Comment: This reminds me of when I was using Microsoft Word back in school (this was when something like Word 97 was current) and tried to use its German grammar checker. It would flag a sentence as incorrect grammatically and suggest an alternative; when I picked that, it flagged *that* as incorrect grammatically and suggested *my original sentence* as an alternative. Hopefully they at least got that kink worked out. (As I recall, I went with the original one I'd written, and it wasn't flagged by the teacher, so *take that, Word!*)

Comment: To be perfectly blunt, Microsoft Word still has better grammar than a lot of the people I know. I see terrible grammar from my work colleagues on a daily basis and it's getting worse. Before too long, software **will** be better at grammar checks than the average Englishman. :(

Comment: Hi, I'm from **10 years in the future.** Grammar and spelling check software improved a lot. Disclaimer: *This comment was not generated via AI tools.*

Answer (score 3):

[Duden Korrektor](http://www.duden.de/shop/software-horbucher/l/produktart-rechtschreibpruefung)

Hey, don't give me that look. There is no better checker on the market for the German language. Trust me.

Answer (score 2):

Grammarly was the best I found for college papers. Double checking is always in your best interest. I do know it saved me tons of time on a deadline.

Answer (score 1):

> If you're thinking that grammar-checking software will help you with your typos and grammar mistakes, think again.

This is precisely what grammar-checking software does. None of them are perfect, but I favor [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com) (as well as a few other people clearly). You have to pay for the premium features, but the subscription is not outrageously expensive (currently $5.83 / month for the first year, $11.66 for the years after).

Answer (score 1):

The best is Grammarly. This is because their software is updated with all the latest rules regarding grammar. Grammarly even suggests changes to segments of sentences to help them read better. It also provides spelling changes and suggests the best words for replacing the more boring words in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

There are many grammar checking software tools out there. For example, grammarly, ginger, and unichecker.

I like grammarly the best, as it not only finds out the errors but also gives a detailed analysis in order to justify the mistake that needs rectification.